how to execute outside hr_main.sql file in docker oracle 21c container
How can I use the SQL file located at 'C:\Users\swans\Downloads\db-sample-schemas-21.1\db-sample-schemas-21.1\human_resources\hr_main.sql' in a Docker Oracle container? When I execute it with '@', it gives me an 'unable to open file' error. Could you please help me if you know how?
@
docker exec -it sqlex /bin/bash 
i want get oracle hr shcema

You shouldn't need to use docker exec to work with a database; you're probably hitting trouble because the container filesystem is isolated from the host's.  You should be able to install a database client on your host system and interact with the container just like any other (possibly-remote) database.
